# Changing an individual element in an integer array does not use property setter in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, properties, inotify

I have 10 Ellipses on my WPF window and I wanted to control its visibility based on an integer array that can hold 10 digits. int array(say arr[10]) is initialized with all zeroes .Based on some logic ,value at certain index changes to 1 during the course of execution.visibility of  Ellipse1 is set to "Visible" when arr[0] =1; visibility of  Ellipse2 is set to "Visible" when arr[1] =1 , ellipse3 -> arr[2]...etc. hope its is clear till now.

in viewmodel I have a property like this

```
 public int[] DisplayOrder
    {
        get { return Model.DisplayOrder; }
        set
        {
            Model.DisplayOrder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DisplayOrder");
        }
    }
```

Now the problem is, when I change ,say arr[3]=1 (initial value was 0), the above mentioned property is NOT CALLED ! had it been called, it would have gone through I notify and my program would have worked as expected. (btw, I have converter to convert value 1 to "Visible"). At the same time if do the initialization for the full array, then property setter is invoked.

Can anyone tell me How should I define my property when I deal with an array so that when individual element of array is changed , it should use property setter to set the new value.

Comment: Look into CollectionViewSource to update the collection or use an ObservableCollection instead of an array.

Comment: That won't work, ObservableCollection will only notify when the collection itself changes. The problem is that he's using an array of integers...in C# you can't just magically tell when an integer field or array element has been changed. He's going to have to make those integers properties in a wrapper class, add INotifyPropertyChanged support and then subscribe to each element's change notification event. Either that or go back to the code that's changing those integers in the first place and work out something there.

Comment: Thanks for responding Guys. As  Mark Feldman Said ObservableCollection will only notify when the collection itself changes.  waiting too see if anybody has an answer. thanks